# <TD> tag does not consider manual line breaks (or ENTER) in HTML

Tags: html

I am trying to enable manual line breaks in `<td>` tag in HTML.

Content is coming from a file which consists of <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or manual line breaks, but while displaying this data in HTML table, data is being displayed continuously. Means it is ignoring manual line breaks.

Is there any way to make `<td>` tag to consider manual line breaks or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> you can say?

***For example:***
Text coming from DataBase:

```
Line 1. 
Line 2. 
Line 3.
```

(with <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after each line)

Data displayed in table cell:

```
Line 1.Line 2.Line 3.
```

(not considering <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after each line)

Tried different ways but failed. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle? Or html you have tried?

Comment: To honor line breaks, you must enclose the text in `<pre></pre>` tags

Comment: @Rino ... I don't know how to add fiddle, so I tried to make my question as obvious as possible.

Comment: Hey Marki .. Thanks a lot, that worked, but it changed my original font and alignment :(

Comment: This depends on the server language that you're working with. For example with PHP you can use nl2br() function, which converts new lines to <br /> tags. Just check how this is implemented in your language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
```

this will covert all enter key pressed to line break

**OR**

You can use 'pre' tag.

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)

Comment: hey Rino and Marki.. Thanks man <pre> tag is working good for enter but now word-wrap: break-word; is not working, it is changing my TD width.

Comment: CSS code i am using right now is 

TABLE{
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 480px;
 }

 TD{
 word-wrap: break-word;
 padding-right: 15px;
 }

Comment: Problem got resolved I used CSS ..... 
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
} ... It is working perfect now .. Thanks all for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is to put your text inside a `span` tag with `white-space: pre-wrap` style, and even more if you are working with Bootstrap (where `pre` tag is styled).

> [CSS white-space Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) (relevant) options:
>
> - pre: Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will only wrap on line breaks. Acts like the  tag in HTML.
> - pre-line: Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks.
> - pre-wrap: Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks.

Comment: Good answer. You can also apply the `white-space: pre-wrap` style directly to the `td` element.